# Ubuntu 18.04 Guest on proxmox host cannot utilise "VirtIO (paravirtualized)" network adapters

Tags: networking, 18.04, virtualization

Hi we have a proxmox host (the host is Ubuntu too) and on it is a VM Ubuntu 18.04 Guest. For reasons I do not understand the command

```
# cat "/boot/config-`uname -r`" | grep -i vir`
```

shows (in the Guest OS) the following

```
CONFIG_VIRTIO_BLK=m 
CONFIG_VIRTIO_NET=m
```

and this Ubuntu Guest cannot use any `VirtIO (paravirtualized)` network adapters (we have to use the `Intel E1000` legacy ones.)

We **have** to use these settings

[image]

EG: If I use the following setting the network **will not work**.
[image]

What is the reason for me having to use Legacy Adapters? does anyone know?

Comment: Log in from the VM console and gather information. Look at `dmesg`. Look at the syslog. Try to bring up the network yourself.

Comment: I have same problem but parent server reachable via ping. Any global host is unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create NAT rules to allow VM public access. Folow [these steps](https://unihost.com/help/settings-nat-proxmox5/) to create NAT. But note that:

- network mask in bit size format can not be aplicable in your system, use full format (255.255.255.0) and test all iptable rulles in CLI
- Since Ubuntu 18.04 you have to use *netplan* to set network or Proxmox DHCP

P.S. Take a look at [qemu-guest-agent](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Qemu-guest-agent)